# Determine the transfer function using these values (Capacitors)

Tags: transistors, transfer-function

This is my circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEu6j7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

These are the values of the components

[image]

Determine the transfer function using these values

[image]

This is what I thought to do in first place but I am not sure, if this it, if I still need to do something.

[image: ad]

Comment: This is not a homework solution service. Show us all of the work you have done so far, and ask specific questions about the circuit.

Comment: A couple more CircuitLab tips: (1) Your circuit has no DC power supply. Add one in. (2) You've chosen a DC source for U1 so after initial switch on nothing is going to happen. (3) Since you have the component values add them into the schematic so we're not nodding up and down. (4) CircuitLab has an arrow symbol (near the bottom) for your U_out reading. (5) Don't forget that after you've done your calculations you can run a simulation on CircuitLab to test.

Comment: `I have found the transfer function in case where the capacitors are equals to infinite...` That depends on what type of analysis you're running here... Are you looking for a high frequency analysis, low frequency analysis, DC analysis, etc.?

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, this is not homework by no means, I have added what I have done regarding the question.

Comment: @Transistor, I have aded the DC source, feel free to change the others. I'm still learning CircuitLab

Comment: @KingDuken, the question comes after having to draw the AC circuit of the circuit, so I am guessing it is AC analysis.

Comment: If it's not homework, then just simulate the circuit. No need to derive equations.

Comment: You are required to find the transfer function. At first, you have calculated one of the corner frequencies..tell us why you did this and how to proceed...

Comment: @LvW, I am not sure I just thought that might be a way to find it . I would appreciate an answer on how to find the transfer function using those values.

Comment: @LvW, can you give me any answer regarding this question